# DataBindingUtil.setContentView - Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds

Tags: android

"Android Studio" shows error message "Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: ViewDataBinding and ActivityChecklistsBinding.

```
ActivityChecklistsBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_checklists);
```

Before update the ADK it works fine. Is there any ideas what wrong?

Comment: although with this error, my project complies and runs perfectly...

Comment: May it will useful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41760397/1318946

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried a couple of things, Clean and Rebuild project.

But, It worked after I choose `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: Can you reduce this answer to the things that did help please?

Comment: I think this is a good solution when you have any doubt regarding if binding updates have been recompiled correctly or not.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not a correct answer

Answer (score 10):

**The binding activity is automatically generated and takes the name from the layout file, not the activity class.**

So if you have an activity named `BeautifulActivity` and the corresponding layout named `sweet_layout.xml`, then the generated name will be `SweetLayoutBinding` and not `BeautifulActivityBinding`.

Don't make my same mistake by confusing between `MainActivity` and `activity_main.xml`

Source [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data)

Answer (score 4):

```
Try This Work for sure...

  Step 1: Add this code in the build.gradle(Mobile:app)
           dataBinding {
                enabled = true
            }

        Example:
         buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }

            **dataBinding {
                enabled = true
            }**
        }

        dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        .....
        }

        Step 2:
        Binding Can be done with Name of the .xml file as below example..
        Simply name of the xml file and prefix with binding...

        Example 1:
        if of your .xml file is activity_main.xml then Binding file should be MainActivityBinding
        Example 2:
        if of your .xml file is android_sunil.xml then Binding file should be AndroidSunilBinding

    Step 3: Sample Code:

    public class BaseObservableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private ActivityBaseobservableBinding activityMainBinding;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_baseobservable);

        }
    }

In the above code my .xml file name is activity_baseobservable so my binding class should be ActivityBaseobservableBinding activityMainBinding


--Happy Android Coding@Ambilpura
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

When I first meet this error, I create a layout named a.xml, and then I Create a Activity like this

```
public class ABinding extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ABinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.a);
    }

}
```

and this error occurs.
Finally I found out Class ABinding was automatically generated in /build, so activity with name ABinding will overwrite the auto generated class

so I rename the Activity and the error disappear

Answer (score 1):

Add this is your build.gradle(Module:app) file

android {

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to layout "main_activity.xml"
Click right -> Refactor -> Rename
Rename the layout to "main_activity_new.xml" or anything you want
Again rename it to normal "main_activity.xml"
```

It fixed for me!

Answer (score 0):

add this in build.gradle

```
   android{
 ....
    dataBinding 
      { 
     enabled = true
       }
...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the solutions mentioned above didn't work out go to your **.gradle folder  >  caches** and delete all folders with name starting with **transforms** i.e. transforms-1 & transforms-2. This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the parent tag is <layout> in the top of the resource file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your XML codes in

Answer (score -2):

You should use **ActivityMainBinding** in place of your Activity class name.

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_checklists);
```