# Data Binding Android - Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds : ViewDataBinding and MainActivity

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 4.
I'm using Android SDK tools 25 rc1. This error persists no matter how many times I clean / rebuild project. File->Invalidate Caches and restart also doesn't work.
I'm not able to run the most basic example of data binding.

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chiragshenoy.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.chiragshenoy.myapplication;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        User user = new User("Test", "User");
        binding.setUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="com.example.chiragshenoy.myapplication.User"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

this is my top level build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You might want to add code for gradle, xml and activity!

Comment: What is your `Gradle` Version? (Not Plugin version) Can be found in `app` (Right Click) -> `Open Module Settings` -> `Project`)

Comment: I found this issue when I updated the android plugins and Gradle and simply invalidate the cache and restart resolved it.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

If your gradle version is ok (1.5+) then you should try this:

1. Go to your "some_layout.xml"
2. Click right -> Refactor -> Rename (or SHIFT + F6)
3. Rename your layout to "some_layout2.xml" for example
4. Rename this file back to the original "some_layout.xml"

This might fix the problem. Let us know.

Comment: worked after renaming. This kind of bug should be solved immediately.

Comment: I upgraded to gradle 2.2.3 and this bug showed up for me. The fix above worked for me! I guess this causes the IDE to properly re-generate the code.

Comment: Worked for me, but why does this issue occur? And why doesn't it go away if I clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: This bug is still occurring with the Android Gradle plugin: 2.3.0-beta4.

Comment: what kind of Bug is this?

Comment: i got this error from all of my layouts but when i renamed one all others fixed too!

Comment: This crazy bug :(( Worked for me too. But why there is still such an awkward issue!

Comment: Android Studio 3.5 stable version google hasn't fixed this bug.

Comment: I just deleted all build folders manually and the problem was gone. For me it happened after android studio updated itself.

Comment: This just happened again after the latest Gradle update. This fix still works.

Comment: It is 2020 and I'm running AS 3.5.3 stable version n still run into this bug but your fix worked

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart fixed the issue in my case

Answer (score 41):

This solution worked for me "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32191257/2205809

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this error by surrounding my xml layout file with the `<layout>` tag

`your_layout.xml` file should look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/view_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</layout>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This was my problem too.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple solution.

1. click "File" on toolbar of android studio
2. click "Invalidate Caches and Restart", then it works.

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer try to explain it a little bit, furthermore in your case, you are giving an answer again an image not attached. Even if it is right.

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

In onCreate

MainActivity isn't the generated Binding class.

Answer (score 4):

I just thought based on **Felipe Gualberto's** [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37364609/1318946) and I got solution difference way.

> If you have written multiple views with the same **id** in different **XML** then make it unique.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One of the quickest hack i use is rename the xml file back and to.

e.g.

rename `abc_layout.xml` to `abc_layout2.xml`. once the binding import shows error rename it back to `abc_layout.xml`.

the short cut to rename is `shift + F6`. its way quicker that entire project rebuild. this will only remove error from one file though.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a `Binding` class will be generated based on the name of the layout file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing "Binding" to it. The above layout file was **main_activity.xml** so the generate class was **MainActivityBinding**. The problem is you are trying to create binding class manually.

This class holds all the bindings from the layout properties (e.g. the user variable) to the layout's `Views` and knows how to assign values for the binding expressions. The easiest means for creating the bindings is to do it while inflating.
No need to restart the Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

in top level Build.Gradle file use  gradle 1.5.0 or above

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```

if it is lower than 1.5.0 then use this one also in top level gradle file

```
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"
```

Comment: He already seems to be using 1.5+ .. I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: tried 1.5.0 also. That too is not working. same error.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to Invalidate caches/Restart from File.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also getting the same problem after [Migrating my existing project to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) and i solve it by doing below things

```
Build -> Clean Project
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

After that

`File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Instead of

```
MainActivity binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the binding class, here **ActivityMainInitBinding** is generated based on the xml file **activity_mail_init.xml**. If you use wrong class the error pops up.

```
  val binding : ActivityMainInitBinding=
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main_init)
```

Answer (score 0):

After migrating to AndoridX, You need to remove old v4 or v7 widgets from the XMl .For ex -  you need to replace if you are using some AppCompat widget like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:tag="showMore"/>
```

Replace it with andoridx widget

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_summary_desc_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="Read More"/>
```

Worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh is of no use if it continues to give errors.
When there are these errors it is likely that in your xml file there is a problem that the compiler did not show you when creating the layout.
In fact, it may happen that this error is visible only in its "debug" folder. If an error of this type should occur, just follow the error in the debug folder and correct it from the original file.
In my case the error was two duplicates of

> xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

that I couldn't see

Answer (score 0):

Delete module level `build` folder and re-open your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because i missed the  tag in view xml, which is not the case here.