# Android Studio 3.0 shows error when data binding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I updated my Android Studio to 3.0 (stable) today. And now, the Android Studio shows an error on `ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`  drawing red underline on `(this, R.layout.activity_main)`.
There is no problem when building and running app. It only makes me uncomfortable with error message.
Here is the error message.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Try Solutions given here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368329/data-binding-android-type-parameter-t-has-incompatible-upper-bounds-viewdata . Hope it helps

Comment: @SnehPandya It was MainActivity.java. Now I solved the problem by solution which is suggested by N.Moudgil.

Comment: @N.Moudgil Thank you! It solved my problem. I thought it was bug of Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 0):

[Update]
My supposed earlier fix was only temporary, as the binding warnings returned when the cache was rebuilt.

However I have finally discovered the actual fix. It turns out that I needed to change my import statements to

```
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;
```

This was not correctly migrated by Android Studio in a previous targetSdk upgrade..

---

**The following did not work for me, but might for you**

For me, this was resolved from Android Studio by "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"
I can't tell you how many months (years?) I put up with this annoying issue before stumbling upon this fix.

Comment: possibly spoke too soon.. the errors came back after the cache rebuilt. Still, this might be useful for someone else, so I'll leave it here.

Comment: My app running properly but the data binding class is not resolved in activity. can you suggest anything to this? already tried invalidate and restart for this but no luck.

Comment: No luck for me either sorry. @SagarNayak if you find a resolution please let me know!

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147609508 . you can download the 4.0 beta or roll back to 3.5.