# Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have been trying to Restfulise the sunflower app example using the githubrowsersample so i have been trying to do a bit of copying and pasting. However, i'm completely confused as to why i am getting this error. This particular code is a complete copy and paste.

The error i am receiving is:

> error: DataBoundViewHolder(T) is not public in DataBoundViewHolder;
>   cannot be accessed from outside package where T is a type-variable: T
>   extends ViewDataBinding declared in class DataBoundViewHolder

and my code is the same as [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/b1a194c1ae267258cd002e2e1c102df7180be473/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/common/DataBoundViewHolder.java) with these imports instead:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.MainThread;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

My DataBoundViewHolder code is also copy and paste:

```
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

/**
 * A generic ViewHolder that works with a ViewDataBinding
 * @param <T> The type of the ViewDataBinding.
 */

public class DataBoundViewHolder<T extends ViewDataBinding> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final T binding;
    DataBoundViewHolder(T binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368329/data-binding-android-type-parameter-t-has-incompatible-upper-bounds-viewdata

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have tried the invalidate cache method, still to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your class `public`

```
    public class DataBoundViewHolder<T extends ViewDataBinding> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ..
}
```

Because now it is `package-private` i suppose

Comment: Not as far as I can see, i'll add the DataBoundViewHolder class in though, as you are right I have missed that out of the opening text.

Comment: @Shade please, accept the answer if it was helpful)

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood what you meant. I have put them in the same hierarchy and they are working. Less complicated talk for anyone else in the same scenario. I put them both in ui/common and it works. Thanks Yuri