# Data binding stops working when upgrade Gradle to 3.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I have just upgraded the version of my Gradle from:

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

to

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

And the data binding from my project has stopped working. I have tried to rebuild the project, even I have tried to entirely delete the `build` folder from my project but with no luck. Android Studio is complaining with the following error:

> Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: ViewDataBinding and ActivityMainBinding

Please see this [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/3zZbphj/Capture.jpg).

If I downgrade to `3.5.0`, everything works fine. How to get rig of this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Binding Android - Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds : ViewDataBinding and MainActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368329/data-binding-android-type-parameter-t-has-incompatible-upper-bounds-viewdata)

Comment: are you using kotlin or java ?

Comment: There is a bug in android studio view binding: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141255511 which is seen only from 3.5.1. As the questioner mentioned, currently downgrading to 3.5.0 solves this problem. We shall wait for the fix to arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do the following:

- Rename your layout to "actvity_main2.xml"
- Rename this file back to the original "actvity_main.xml"

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I wonder what the issue is though, because the data binding generated code was already there and shouldn't need to be rebuilt. Even doing a rebuild didn't fix it. Any idea what the problem is?